# Why can't I use <script> in Blazor Wasm razor file?

Tags: javascript, razor, blazor

I created a new Blazor Wasm project to test this. In Index.razor, I added the code

```
<textarea rows="1"
      oninput="adjustRows(this)">
</textarea>

<textarea rows="1"
      oninput="
        this.rows = 1;
        this.rows = Math.round(this.scrollHeight / this.clientHeight);">
</textarea>

<script>
    function adjustRows(textarea) {
        // reset to 1 row to get clientHeight
        textarea.rows = 1;
        textarea.rows = Math.round(textarea.scrollHeight / textarea.clientHeight);
    }
</script>
```

Both textareas should incerase their height automatically, but only the second one does so. The first one throws the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: adjustRows is not defined at HTMLTextAreaElement.oninput ((index):1:1)".

What is happening here? Why can't I use the `<script>`?

Comment: In normal html/javascript, this would work. Does it stop complaining if you move the script ahead of the textinput?

Comment: I just had the same idea, but no, this also does not work.

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure it worked once, because I published it that way in August and most likely tested it beforehand.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Blazor requires the script to be a static asset of some kind, i.e.: not part of the component. I get Error RZ9992 if I try to include a script element in the component.

Comment: Hm, when I checkout the commit from August and run it from Visual Studio 2022, it does not work. But when I open the archived published version from netlify, it works. So, maybe, this is a bug in Visual Studio that came with 17.8?

Comment: That could be. Not sure there's a way to tell now. I was playing around with it on replit.com. I'm not sure what they're using for the Blazor support. If you remove the function-calling `oninput`, does it then complain about the script element? I'm thinking the complaint about the function not existing is a secondary issue. I feel it should be reporting the script block as the main issue instead.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. Why should it still complain about not finding the function, when I remove the call?

Comment: It wouldn't. It should instead complain about the script block existing in the component. I'm thinking that, if the script block existing in the component is an error, then that it turn would cause the function-doesn't-exist error. I'm assuming that the error you initially got is not the error you should be getting.

Comment: There is no error, when I remove the call.

Comment: Hrm. All I can say at this point is that your code doesn't look like other examples of an index.razor file. But you said this has worked in an earlier incarnation so that's probably a trivial detail. Maybe somebody else with better/more/other expertise will come along.

Answer (score 1):

Full explained in [JavaScript location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#javascript-location) documentation:

> **Don't place a `<script>` tag in a Razor component file (.razor) because the  tag can't be updated dynamically by Blazor.**
>
> Load JavaScript (JS) code using any of the following approaches:
>
> - Load a script in `<head>` markup (Not generally recommended)
> - Load a script in `<body>` markup
> - Load a script from an external JavaScript file (.js) collocated with a component
> - Load a script from an external JavaScript file (.js)
> - Inject a script before or after Blazor starts